# So [X] it's [opposite of X]

Tags: phrase-requests, rhetorical-devices

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes the specific type of word-play or idiom in these examples::

> - The movie *Rocky Horror Picture Show* is so bad that it's good.
> - Chinese Crested Hairless dogs are so ugly they're cute.
> - Eating these high-fat triple-chocolate brownies is so right that it's wrong.

<sub>(BTW: The above are not my actual opinions, just examples of the usage I am asking about!)</sub>

I had thought about ***[chiasmus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus)***, but it doesn't fit exactly.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Notice they all use the same construction? Something like _so `X` that `Opp`(`X`)_. It's an idiomatic construction, of which there are thousands in English. And there isn't a special Greek name for this one; the Greeks weren't talking about English.

Comment: I never understand why some people use such meaningless juxtapositions without apparently realising how stupid they sound. If something is "bad", it's bad. It doesn't suddenly become "good" if it's *really* bad. Perhaps it's based on the idea that if you travel far enough west, you end up in the east. But it makes no sense to me - all I can see is that people senselessly apply the *so X it's Y* idiom thinking there's some potentially "clever" meaning to *so X it's ~X*, even if *they* don't know what they mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  I agree!  Rocky Horror is just plain bad.  Chinese Cresteds are just plain ugly.  And as long as done in moderation, one should fully enjoy brownies.  But the construction still exists, I am just trying to put a name on it.

Comment: @Fumble I’m not sure I quite agree with that. There are movies that are enjoyable to watch because they are so poorly made that they become unintentionally funny. I agree that _Rocky Horror_ isn’t one, but they do exist. And some people enjoy such movies almost more than good movies. And then there are cases where something can _feel so good it hurts_ (semantically, though not verbally, identical), or the opposite: something can hurt so much you go numb.

Comment: @cobaltduck: Don't forget to leave a trail of breadcrumbs so you can find your way out again if you follow this link, but it's worth noting that tvtropes points out... [*Keep in mind that even when something is So Bad, It's Good, it's **still bad.***](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Sobaditsgood). (If you get stuck there for the rest of the day, don't say I didn't warn you! :)

Comment: @Janus: I might almost have to concede that point. Generally speaking I wouldn't waste my time watching something a movie so badly made that unintentionally it becomes amusing, but I can't deny I was fascinated by [*Reefer Madness*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0028346/). Originally an anti-drug propaganda film in the 30s, the restored 2004 release turns it into something totally different. The social context has radically changed for many viewers, and the weird use of colourised smoke is a masterstroke. I love it (but for all the wrong reasons, I'm sure director Louis J. Gasnier would say).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The only thing I could think of that applied was referenced in your reference [Springtime for Hitler](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpringtimeForHitler)

Comment: Much comedy derives from exaggeration of the so-bad-it's-good type. John Cleese, say, may play a character who is so insufferable that he's enjoyable to watch. But consciousness of the exaggeration is essential to the enjoyment: He's making a fool of himself (or of insufferable twits in general), and that makes the objectively awful experience enjoyable. What distinguishes so-bad-it's-good fare of the _Mystery Science Theater 3000_ variety from that of the _Fawlty Towers_ variety is the former's innocence of irony—it's ridiculous by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a non-searchable and potentially ephemeral comment to the original posting, Professor Lawler kindly presented the following answer:

> Notice they all use the same construction? Something like:
>
> > so **X** that **Opp(X)**
>
> It’s an idiomatic construction, of which there are thousands in English. And there isn’t a special Greek name for this one; the Greeks weren’t talking about English.

I’ve marked this posting Community Wiki because it is John’s answer not my own, and so I deserve no reputation from it.

Comment: Accepting due to these these words only: "there isn’t a special Greek name for this one".

Answer (score 2):

Phrases that follow the template of a popular saying like “so bad it’s good” are called [*snowclones*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/146778). The term comes from “Eskimos have X words for snow,” another very popular snowclone.

Answer (score 0):

*Paradox* comes to mind. [Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradox):

> Something (such as a situation) that is made up of two opposite things and that seems impossible but is actually true or possible

*Oxymoron* (e.g. "extreme pacifist") is also [called](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/oxymoronterm.htm) "a compressed paradox". In this case it is not compressed to my vision, so I'd stick with *paradox*.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *aggressive pacifist*?

Comment: The example is taken from the second link above. *Aggressive pacifist* works as well, and it is a more clear example of an oxymoron.

Comment: While I respect Bones' clinical skills, her language ability (like her social skills) is often pompous at best and distorted at worst. *Extreme* does not suggest violence, just as *pacifism* does not suggest passivity.